# Clear specific cell ranges based on text in column A

Tags: vba, excel

I need to clear out specific cell ranges in the rows that have the word "Actual" in column A.  I have been experimenting with the following code that works, however it is extremely slow because it needs to process through three IF statements to clear out the discontinuous ranges B:E,I:J,N:O.  Does anyone have ideas as how to combine the three if statements into one statement, and/or provide ideas on how to speed up this code?  Thank you for your consideration.

```
Sub ClearWeeklyActualPHSR()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
'Purpuse: clears specific cell ranges if column A = "Actual"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False                      'Disable screen refresh
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual           'Switch calculation mode to manual (speeds up calculation)

'Counts number of rows in column A
lr = Sheets("Actual Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr
    'If "Actual" in column A, then clear contents of columns B:E,I:J,N:O for those rows.
    If Sheets("Actual Data").Cells(i, "A") = "Actual" Then Cells(i, "B").Resize(1, 4).ClearContents
    Cells(i, "I").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
    Cells(i, "N").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True                       'Enable Auto calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic        'Switch calculation mode back to auto
End Sub
```

Comment: You only need **1** `If` in the loop.

Comment: Gary, that did the trick!  Speed increased 10 fold.  Thank you.  I updated the code above to reflect the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is untested**, but may serve as a template:

```
Sub ClearWeeklyActualPHSR()
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long
    'Purpuse: clears specific cell ranges if column A = "Actual" - SUB is SLOW

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                      'Disable screen refresh
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual           'Switch calculation mode to manual (speeds up calculation)

    'Counts number of rows in column A
    With Sheets("Actual Data")
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            'If "Actual" in column A, then clear contents of columns B:E,I:J,N:O for those rows.
            If .Cells(i, "A") = "Actual" Then
                Union(.Cells(i, "B").Resize(1, 4), .Cells(i, "I").Resize(1, 2), .Cells(i, "N").Resize(1, 2)).ClearContents
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                       'Enable Auto calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic        'Switch calculation mode back to auto
End Sub
```

Comment: Tested.  A more elegant and slightly faster solution.  Thanks again!